# Dynamic includes in JSP template

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, include

I've just started studying Spring, and I'm trying to make a web application. I have some common UI elements such as footer, header, sidebar and also want to add dynamic blocks, i.e. widgets. What widgets to include need to be chosen in Java code, not JSP template.

And that's where I'm stuck. Every controller returns it's own view - `main.jsp` which includes some static and dynamic blocks:

```
 <jsp:include page="head.jsp" />  
     <c:forEach items="${viewList}" var="viewName">
                 <jsp:include page="${viewName}.jsp" />    
    </c:forEach>
...
```

In controler I'm passing view list and object that will be used as widget to model:

```
 ...
 views.add(moduleOne.getViewName());
 views.add(moduleTwo.getViewName());
 model.addAllAttributes(moduleOne.getAttr());  
 model.addAllAttributes(moduleTwo.getAttr());  
 model.addAttribute(IModule.VIEW_LIST, views); // passing all views that will be included into main.jsp
 ...
 return "main";
```

But it doesn't work because when I use `jsp:include page` model parameters do not pass to includee. Also I can't `%@include file=` because in that case I won't be able to use variables and I would need to know which view to pass at compile time.

Of course if there's no solution, I'll have to hardcode all possible widget views in `main.jsp` and switch between them:

```
   switch($i) {
    case 1: 
          include file=widget1.jsp;
          break;
    case 2: 
        include file=widget2.jsp;
        break;
      ...                    
    }
```

Which is obviously not flexible.

So, the questions are:

1. Is there any way to solve the problem of passing model to include views without using 
   `%@include file=` and make my widgets working?
2. Is there some better way to implement such widgets structure?

Thank you!

Comment: did your tried to dump the request attributes in your included `JSP`s? just to verify that the *included request* still contains them. If they are there, they are accessible.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez what do you mean? For example, I set some classes and and other attributes to model, and they were available only in first included view. Other views didn't get them. Am I understood you?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you cant use the `<%@ include`.  I did this in a project where I needed to do a "wizard" that used one form but multiple jsp fragments.  I just had a Enum I set in my model that determined which fragment I should load, and used a `c:choose` in the JSP.

Comment: @MaximOstrovsky no, I mean, go to your `${viewName}.jsp` pages and add a Java Snippet (for debug purposes) in which you iterate through the request's attributes and output them to the JSP. That would help to know whether the attributes are present in the included request or not

Comment: @CodeChimp he can not use `@include` because that one works statically (the servlet container merges the contents of the included page into the calling one before transforming the JSP in a servlet class). In Maxim code the page to be included is only known at runtime, so he needs a way of including it dynamically, hence the `<jsp:include/>` tag, which uses a `RequestDispatcher` to perform the include operation (no merging of JSPs during compile time).

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez, so I tried to do what you recomend, and was a litle bit surprised. I wrote requestScope in all include view.  
 All included views contains all atributes I need. But I don't why this attributes pass vaibales only in main.jsp and 1st included view. 
 2nd included view doesn't out this attributes although they exists in requestScope. I have no idea why...

Comment: @MaximOstrovsky I guess we will need to see portions of the code from those included views plus the output you got when doing the *request dump* in at least the two first ones... this looks like a tricky one!

Comment: @MaximOstrovsky if u want to use dynamic Ui then configure tiles api in your spring mvc it is most powerful in UI

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a model attribute to decide which file to include like

```
model.addAttribte("fileToInclude",IncludeFile.HEADER);
```

and then

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${fileToInclude == 'HEADER'}">
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But there is a much better and cleaner way. use a decorator like SiteMesh then you can have different decorators applied to your views.Try it out [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh3/SiteMesh+3+Overview)